Is there a template for lecture notes similar to the MIT SICP notes?
I was wondering if there is any LaTeX template for the MIT Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs lecture notes. I want to provide similar handout notes to students, along with the lecture slides, like the following screenshot:

My initial thought was to use article class with beamerarticle package and simply manually insert each slide as a wrapfig and write the notes next to it. Ideally, the text would come from the accompanying notes on the Beamer slides.
Is there a more automated approach than the above? Also, how can I insert the notes from a Beamer slide using the beamerarticle class?
Thanks!

Can you please make your question self-sustained so that people will still be able to understand what you are looking for even if the link stops working?

Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz; I added a screenshot of what I want in lecture notes/handout format.

Is alternating the slide position left/right a must have?

Not necessarily. It might help slightly with the reading flow by clarifying where the slide change happens, but it is subjective. A solution without alternation would also be great.

In this case, I would use beamer in handout mode and use pdfpages to position slides and note pages next to each other.

I ended up doing something similar. Is there an easy way to include the notes in the article and not show them as PDF images? That way, if longer, the notes can wrap around the figure. An easy way would be to have notes as separate files for each slide and then input that file as TeX. Is there an easier way to extract node contents using the beamerarticle class? Thanks!
